# New Ethereum Account with Infura

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, infura

Can I create a new ethereum account using Infura like we do using `web3.personal.newAccount()`;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK Infura doesn't allow the creation of new Account (personal_newAccount api) for security reason.

However, the creation of an account has nothing to do with an Ethereum node but it results from cryptography mechanisms.
You can find several JavaScript libraries online which implements the crypto to generate an Ethereum account.

One of those is [keythereum](https://github.com/ethereumjs/keythereum)

Example:

```
var keythereum = require("keythereum");

var params = { keyBytes: 32, ivBytes: 16 };

var dk = keythereum.create(params);
console.log(dk)
```